# Mounting bluetooth as local drive

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, bluetooth

I know you can easily browse files on a device by using bluetooth, this is not what I wanna do.

I want to mount the bluetooth device (an Android phone, for example) just like when I mount a usb drive or a network storage: that is with its directory listed in the filesytem under /Volumes.

Is there any extension/plugin which does this on Mac Os X Mavericks? This behavior works perfectly under Ubuntu.

Why I want to do it? Because a few application I use will only read files from the filesystem and it would be useful to me to have them read what's on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you can try is [FUSE for OS X](https://osxfuse.github.io/) and [btfs](http://www.mulliner.org/bluetooth/btfs.php). Not sure if it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I really don't think that a software that no one seems to care since 2005 (built against some ancient linux kernel version) could possibly work on Os X, and mavericks in particular.
Also note that if you search for "btfs osx" or similar this answer is the first link that pops up... I understrand that no one has ever even tried to do it :-(